# VBScript Admin CMD Command Executed Remotely

Tags: windows, scripting, vbscript

Trying to execute a simple dns flush remotely from a machine, but for one reason or the other - I need to run the cmd as admin. The cmd runs fine under the account physically in person, but you need to do the whole right click -> run as admin bit.

Right now, remotePC is set to local or '.'

```
 Set shl = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Input remote PC
 remotePC = "."

'Command which will be executed
 strCommand = "cmd.exe /C cd C:\WINDOWS\system32 & ipconfig.exe /flushdns & pause"

'Connect to the remote PC
'Impersonate with the default level?
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & remotePC & "\root\cimv2")

Set objProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")

errReturn = objProcess.Create(strCommand, null, null, intProcessID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`PsExec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) for this purpose. Don't bother with VBScript.

Comment: I still need to script this though. It needs to be automatic not manual.

Comment: I made a VBscript to automatically run PsExec, but even with PsExec and loggin in with credentials - it still asks for elevated command prompt.

Comment: Got it! Used -s with PsExec in the VBscript

Comment: wshShell.run("cmd /k psexec \\REMOTEPC -u userhere -p " & password & " -s ipconfig /flushdns")